# Windows OS Button Style CSS

Tags: css, button

Can anyone guess what CSS styling I should apply to a button to guess this exact look.

[image]

**Note: I realize this is the default look for for unstyled buttons on Windows** and that I don't have to apply any CSS to get this style, but on Mac and Linux it's not the same, so I can't depend on the default styling of the OS for this. I would have to force this style myself in the css. Anyone knows what CSS styling can consistently produce this effect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Examples

**Firefox 3.6.12**

[image: Firefox button]

**Safari 5.0.3**

[image: Safari Button]

**Chrome 8**

[image: Chrome button]

**Internet Explorer 8**

[image: Internet Explorer 8 Button]

For some reason, IE8's propriety `filter` property didn't work (it should).

#### HTML

```
<button>
    <span>
       <span>
          Submit
       </span>   
    </span>
</button>
```

It seems to work better cross browser with 2 child elements. Using the `button` itself as the outer element caused a few issues.

#### CSS

```
button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;   
}

button span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 0;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #F0F0F0 50%, #D4D4D4 50%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#F0F0F0), color-stop(50%,#D4D4D4));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F0F0F0', endColorstr='#D4D4D4',GradientType=0 );
}

button span span {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ttxxz/).

Comment: wow, pretty good. Thank you. Can someone confirm this works on Mac and Linux.

Comment: @silow I think the browser is more relevant. The rounded corners will not work < IE9. The gradient will work > IE6.

Answer (score 9):

OK, since I can't see your image, I just took a default button look on my OS (Windows 7). The styling would be something like this (only Firefox taken into account, as I'm too lazy to do a cross-browser version):

```
a.button {
    height: 18px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #707070;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2 0%, #EBEBEB 50%, #DDDDDD 51%, #CFCFCF 100%);
    font: normal 12px sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ECF7FD;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #3C7FB1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EAF6FD 0%, #D9F0FC 50%, #BEE6FD 51%, #A7D9F5 100%);
}
a.button:active {
    padding: 2px 7px 3px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #73A7C4;
    border-bottom: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #2C628B;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E5F4FC 0%, #C4E5F6 50%, #98D1EF 51%, #68B3DB 100%);
}
```

This is a CSS-only version using CSS3. It won't work in Internet Explorer and Opera will not render the background gradients. So you're best off using images instead of pure CSS.

[EDIT]

A more complete implementation: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUsxy/1/) (feel free to add IE filters and some sort of fallback for Opera and edit my answer to post it - BE BOLD :))

```css
a.button {
    height: 18px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #707070;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #707070;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2 0%, #EBEBEB 50%, #DDDDDD 51%, #CFCFCF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0,#F2F2F2), color-stop(0.5,#EBEBEB),color-stop(0.51,#DDDDDD),color-stop(1,#CFCFCF));
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2 0%, #EBEBEB 50%, #DDDDDD 51%, #CFCFCF 100%);
    font: normal 12px sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ECF7FD;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #3C7FB1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #3C7FB1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #3C7FB1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EAF6FD 0%, #D9F0FC 50%, #BEE6FD 51%, #A7D9F5 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0,#EAF6FD), color-stop(0.5,#D9F0FC),color-stop(0.51,#BEE6FD),color-stop(1,#A7D9F5));
    background: linear-gradient(top, #EAF6FD 0%, #D9F0FC 50%, #BEE6FD 51%, #A7D9F5 100%);
}
a.button:active {
    padding: 2px 7px 3px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #73A7C4;
    border-bottom: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #2C628B;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #2C628B;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #2C628B;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E5F4FC 0%, #C4E5F6 50%, #98D1EF 51%, #68B3DB 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0,#E5F4FC), color-stop(0.5,#C4E5F6),color-stop(0.51,#98D1EF),color-stop(1,#68B3DB));
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Click me</a>
```

[Edit 2]

Edited to include IE's Filter. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/aUsxy/3/

Comment: That is pretty cool - it uses less markup than mine, but at the expense of being less browser compatible (though I know you did mention that).

Comment: Yeah, full browser compatibility can be achieved with background images (a 1x18px line will suffice) and some black magic like PIE.htc or similar to emulate the border radius and box shadow in IE.

Comment: You can also use the IE filter: for css gradients :)

Comment: I edited my answer to add a jsfiddle example. You can enrich it if you wish :)

Comment: @Kyle Your jsfiddle link is dead. Can you please put your code here in form of code snippet?

Comment: As of now, neither [`box-shadow`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) nor [`border-radius`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) need a prefix in any major browser.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good tutorial on getting the effect you are after:

http://www.monc.se/kitchen/59/scalable-css-buttons-using-png-and-background-colors

It's quite difficult to style a button exactly like that, and in a usable scalable format.

An alternative is to simulate an HTML button, have it as a div with a background image and write some Javascript to simulate the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set of images as button backgrounds. A set, not a single image, so you can have buttons of different width in your site.

Answer (score 0):

Possible variant - image with [9-slice scaling](http://hempton.com/examples/scale9grid/), like that:

```
$('.example').scale9Grid({top:10,bottom:10,left:10,right:10});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate gradients you need with http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor for `.button` and for `.button:hover`. So you'll get exactly what you want.