# links looking like submit buttons

Tags: html, css

I want my html link to look like a real submit button. Any good codes with css? I have found some examples, but I want it to be more real than just a grey box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What CSS will produce this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375255/what-css-will-produce-this)

Answer (score 2):

Make a button image in your favourite image precessing tool and use these codes:

HTML

```
<a href="whatever/link.fil" class="link_button">&nbsp;</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link_button
{
    background-image: url(path/to/button_image.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 79px; /*your image width*/
    height: 35px: /*your image height*/
}
```

That should set up your link to look like a nicely styled button, that you created.

If you don't want to use an image, you can use normal CSS borders and baackground colors/gradients as well.

Regarding the `&nbsp;` this is so no text is shown on the image itself, another way to do this is with css: `text-indet: -9999px;` or you can use the text as part of the element like normal and just style the background :)

Comment: Suggestion: put some real text inside the `<a>` and hide the text in CSS with e.g. a large, negative `text-indent`. It's better for accessibility (screen readers can say the link), plus when using a non-graphical browser, I can see the link.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you'd like to create links that look like buttons, but a bit nicer than the standard old grey box?

There are tons of tutorials out there for this: just search "css buttons". A good one is this: http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

Answer (score 0):

If your widget toolkit's theme does some snazzy theming (most do), you most likely won't be able to reproduce the button's look. Even if you could, it would only emulate your computer's theme.

Of course, if you don't mind your button not being consistent with normal buttons, there are many tutorials that allow you to create nice CSS buttons.

If you could consider actually using a button rather than a link, that'd probably be even better.

Comment: Is there a way to add a link with request params to button? As far as I know, not.

Comment: Yes, there is. A form with a submit button, and put the request params in `input type="hidden"` tags.

Comment: Can you give an example? I mean page.html?param=paramvalue

Comment: `<form action="page.html"><input type="hidden" name="param" value="paramvalue"><input type="submit" value="text here"></form>`